# Runge-Kutta 4th order for 4 coupled first order differential equation

Tags: ode, runge-kutta

I have to solve 4 coupled first order differential equations for $f(t)$ ,$g(t)$, $h(t)$ and $w(t)$ witch are only functions of $t$ , but for every reference link a function of 3 variables is assumed (i.e http://www.phy.davidson.edu/FacHome/dmb/py200/RungeKuttaMethod.htm)

I wonder if anyone could enlighten me on this problem,the equations are:

$\frac{df}{dt} = \alpha f -\beta f + \theta g - (f+h)f$

$\frac{dg}{dt} = \psi f- \phi g$

$\frac{dh}{dt} = \xi f+ \mu h -\tau h + \epsilon w- (f+h)h$

$\frac{dw}{dt} = \nu h - \chi h$

Comment: Look at the examples here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html.

Comment: Thanks , but I use C and Python. Not familiar with MATLAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Zombie_Apocalypse_ODEINT) is a Python example using `scipy.integrate.odeint`. It doesn't use a Runge-Kutta method, but by changing the `scipy.integrate.odeint` to `scipy.integrate.ode` and using the `set_integrator` method to set the integrator to “dopri5”, you can use a Runge-Kutta 4(5) method to solve your equations.

Comment: But its my first time with numerical models , so I would like to have a implementation..

Comment: It may be time to learn how to take verbal explanations and turn them into code yourself.